# How to check if the value of the column is in array list- Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I wanted to check the customer Ids which are in the parameters.

This is my sample data.

Customer ID,Customer Name,Contact Person,Phone Number,Email Address

1001,ABC Inc.,John Smith,555-1234,john@abc.com

1002,XYZ Corp.,Jane Doe,555-5678,jane@xyz.com

1003,Acme Co.,Bob Johnson,555-2468,bob@acme.com

1004,Smith & Sons,Mary Smith,555-3698,mary@smith.com

1005,Jones Inc.,Tom Jones,555-7890,tom@jones.com

I have an array list and it is passed as a parameter to data flow. I added this as a new column along with the above data. After adding my data looks like this.

Customer ID,Customer Name,Contact Person,Phone Number,Email Address, Customer_profit_array

1001,ABC Inc.,John Smith,555-1234,john@abc.com,[1001,1002,1007]

1002,XYZ Corp.,Jane Doe,555-5678,jane@xyz.com,[1001,1002,1007]

1003,Acme Co.,Bob Johnson,555-2468,bob@acme.com,[1001,1002,1007]

1004,Smith & Sons,Mary Smith,555-3698,mary@smith.com,[1001,1002,1007]

1005,Jones Inc.,Tom Jones,555-7890,tom@jones.com,[1001,1002,1007]

Now, I want to display `yes` whenever customer id is available in that array. In the above example row1 and row2 should have `yes` and others should have value as `no`.

I tried giving expression for that column as `iif({Customer ID} in $Customer_profit_array, 'Yes','No')`. But this is not a valid expression. How to solve this?

Comment: Try using contain function. Expression: `iif(contains($param1,#item=={Customer ID}),'Yes','No')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the data is in array, you can use `contain` function in dataflow.

**Syntax:**
`contains(<value1> : array, <value2> : unaryfunction)`

The result of contains function will be of Boolean type.

- Give the expression for new column as, `iif(contains({ Customer_profit_array},#item=={Customer ID}),'Yes','No')`.

[image: derived column expression]

This expression checks if `customer id` is in `Customer_profit_array` column.

**Output**

| **Customer ID** | **Customer Name** | **Contact Person** | **Phone Number** | **Email Address** | **Customer_profit_array** | **customer_available** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | ABC Inc. | John Smith | 555-1234 | john@abc.com | [1001,1002,1007] | Yes |
| 1002 | XYZ Corp. | Jane Doe | 555-5678 | jane@xyz.com | [1001,1002,1007] | Yes |
| 1003 | Acme Co. | Bob Johnson | 555-2468 | bob@acme.com | [1001,1002,1007] | No |
| 1004 | Smith & Sons | Mary Smith | 555-3698 | mary@smith.com | [1001,1002,1007] | No |
| 1005 | Jones Inc. | Tom Jones | 555-7890 | tom@jones.com | [1001,1002,1007] | No |

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#contains